# In Highcharts, how to avoid auto tick interval in a container with limited height

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I found out that, when the container's height is very small, the y-axis' tick interval will be different from what you have assigned to `yAxis.tickInterval`.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/scottszb1987/9qgzerwn/

As you can see, even with `yAxis.tickInterval` set to 4, the appearance of the interval is 12 in the example.

I'm wondering, is this a Highcharts' mechanism to prevent axis label / grid line overlapping? Is there any way we could force the tick interval to display as what we set up regardless on the height of the container?

Comment: I don't really get what you want to do. You want to use the whole space for the height?

Comment: Nope. More straight forward,  my yAxis.tickInterval is 4, however due to limited container height, Highcharts shows a chart with tickInterval of 12, I want it to be still 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have equal interval between ticks.
You can use the [tickPositioner](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.tickPositioner) function

```
yAxis: {
      tickPositioner: function () {
                var positions = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < this.dataMax; i+=4){
                positions.push(i);
                }
                return positions;
                }
  },
```

I've updated your [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/yvbenitah/9qgzerwn/2/)

I hope I've helped you

Comment: Feedfedfat, That's not the solution you were waiting for ?

Comment: Hi IsraGab, this is a great answer, it does solve my problem, thanks a lot!